Who wins if the board has 3 kings and 2 threes
The board has 3 kings and 2 threes. One player has a 3 and a 10 in the hole. The other player has a jack and a nine in the hole. Who would win the hand?

See this and this (in the latter, see part 6 in the accepted answer). Does that answer your question?

The cards in the board make a full house, Kings over Threes. Neither player has a hole card that can improve over this.  Their hole cards are irrelevant. Both play the board.  They tie, and split the pot.
Perhaps you think that the trip threes make a difference? It doesn't. Only the 5 cards in the hand matter. Other cards are irrelevant.
